# Parsing custom dates performance in TSQL

Tags: performance, date, t-sql, format

What would be the fastest way to parse out a custom date from an imported CSV?
The format of the date in the file is: `Mddyyyy`
I am currently using `DATEFROMPARTS` in both my `SELECT` and `JOIN`

`SELECT`:

```
, DATEFROMPARTS(
    RIGHT([s].[Birthdate], 4)
    , LEFT([s].[Birthdate], LEN([s].[Birthdate]) - 6)
    , LEFT(RIGHT([s].[Birthdate], 6), 2)
) AS [Birthdate]
```

`JOIN`: (the 1900 date is because I am also checking for NULL dates when updating a record)

```
AND CASE
    WHEN [t].[Birthdate] IS NULL THEN
        '1900-01-01'
    ELSE
    DATEFROMPARTS(
        RIGHT([s].[Birthdate], 4)
        , LEFT([s].[Birthdate], LEN([s].[Birthdate]) - 6)
        , LEFT(RIGHT([s].[Birthdate], 6), 2)
                )
END = ISNULL([t].[Birthdate], '1900-01-01')
```

Converting the target table date ended up taking a bit longer for the `JOIN`:

```
AND ISNULL([s].[Birthdate], '') = ISNULL(FORMAT([t].[Birthdate],'Mddyyyy'), '')
```

Comment: That `JOIN` won't be SARGable. Honestly, when you consume the data from your CSV you should be converting it to the relevant data type as part of your ETL. Also, if you want `NULL`s to be equal, use an `OR`, not `ISNULL`: `(A = B OR (A IS NULL AND B IS NULL))`

Comment: Only one digit for Month? How do you cater for the last 3 months?

Comment: The OP already does, @Stu , with `LEN({Column}) - 6`.

Comment: @Larnu "when you consume the data from your CSV you should be converting it to the relevant data type as part of your ETL" is the answer to my question.  I ended up using ```Import-Csv .\s.csv | ForEach-Object {$_.Birthdate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Birthdate.PadLeft(8,'0'), 'MMddyyyy', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') $_ } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation .\t.csv``` in PowerShell before the import.

Comment: @Daniel - Just making sure... You last post means that your issue has been solved, correct?

Comment: @JeffModen Yes, solved.  Is there a way to note that Larnu's comment is the solution?